# "match" vs "fill' dimensions of a 2D object

Tags: word-usage, differences

**Question**

I apparently misunderstand the use of "fill" and "match" as used in the situations described in the context below.

I take "fill" to mean "taking up the empty internal volume of something, padding (wall thickness) implicitly taken into account as not available". If there is anything else in the container, "filling" will take up the space that is left (or displace the other object).

"Matching", to me, is more context dependent, and may mean equaling the internal or external dimensions (or both - "a matching set"), or a (part of) a shape. When used for volume, it may still mean internal or external, but no other objects are considered.

I am guessing some part of this is wrong. Which of my assumptions are wrong? Please offer some examples.

**Context:**

The question regards the terms `fill_parent` and [`match_parent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#MATCH_PARENT) (same effect, different names) in Android programming.

**[edit]** In short: Google have changed the name of the behavior of stretching only in the available space (which is *rarely* all of it) from `fill_parent` to `match_parent`. I don't see why "match" is better than "fill" to describe it.

Consider the following:

[image: water in glass]

The grey area ("glass") is a rectangle with padding on 3 sides. The blue area ("water") is inside the "glass".

If there are other elements in the "glass", asking the "water" to fill/match the "glass" may, depending on other factors, either produce the same result, or take up the *remaining* space.

Note that in this context, a "child view" can be larger than its parent - it will be clipped or scrolled - the parent can act *more like a window than a container*.

Many - Google included - insist that "match" is a more appropriate term than "fill". [Here is an example of what they may find confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36638210/1034042) ("HOW YOU CAN GET TRIPPED UP"). The XML at the end of that answer is for a red rectangle trying to "match" the height of the screen, with 2 other rectangles already there. It produces this:

[image: trying to match height of screen]

My opinion: sure, with other elements present it doesn't fill, but neither does it match. In fact, "matching the parent", to me, even more strongly suggests that it should be the same size, than "filling the parent" does. "[What Google says, goes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23132050/1034042)" isn't an explanation.

[My deleted question on SO](https://web.archive.org/web/20151031182929/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239891/whats-the-layout-logic-that-motivates-the-term-match-parent-over-fill-paren) has more details, if you're interested. It was asking about layout logic I may have been unaware of. Here, I'm asking about the meaning of words.

The XML for my layout (glass, water)is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/glass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="30dip"
    android:paddingLeft="30dip"
    android:paddingRight="30dip"
    android:background="#B0B0B0">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/water"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#9090F8" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[Chat link here.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39665/fill-vs-match-dimensions)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the design intent of *fill_parent* and *match_parent*, taken from your link:

> Special value for the height or width requested by a View. FILL_PARENT means that the view wants to be as big as its parent, minus the parent's padding, if any.
>
> Special value for the height or width requested by a View. MATCH_PARENT means that the view wants to be as big as its parent, minus the parent's padding, if any.

Note that the design intent is identical, all the way down to the value assigned in each case (a value of -1).

The gist of your question is:

> I don't see why "match" is better than "fill" to describe it.

*Fill* is a term that has an established use in computer graphics:

> In graphics applications, to paint the inside of an enclosed object.
> [- webopedia](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/F/fill.html)

Based on this established meaning, the term *FILL_PARENT* sounds as if the intent is to paint the parent object, when the actual intent has nothing to do with operations on the parent. It's therefore a bad choice of words for the identifier.

On the other hand, *MATCH_PARENT* has the natural English meaning related to copying (but not changing) properties about the parent object, which is **much closer to the design intent** for that term (an excellent *match* for it, if you'd excuse the pun):

> **Match** *verb*
> [with object] Be equal to (something) in quality or strength
> [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/match)

tl;dr - *FILL_PARENT* implies an operation on the parent whereas *MATCH_PARENT* implies changing the child to resemble the parent in some way (the measurements that are to match are specified in the first quote of this answer). Since the intent is to modify the child rather than the parent, *MATCH_PARENT* is more suitable than *FILL_PARENT*.

Comment: Yes, I did write "same effect, different names". I know it's considered "much closer to the design intent", my question is *why*. Would you please clarify the last part a bit? Things to keep in mind: Padding - child views will NOT be equal in size to parent. "Sibling' rectangles will make them even smaller. From your description it feels that "fill" - implying "inside" - actually fits *better* than "match", which implies exact equality.

Comment: @kaay It's the difference between operating on the parent object (fill) and copying properties from the parent object (match). The implication of 'inside' isn't particularly relevant to the distinction.

Comment: @kaay I've added a summary to my answer that should clarify the last part, as requested.

Comment: Thank you. Even though such a thing has never occurred to me in the context of "setting a view's height to `fill_parent`", it makes sense. As I am the one with a wrong way of thinking, however, I don't feel qualified to select an answer as correct - I'll wait for other votes.

Comment: @kaay You're welcome :) . [This recent meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7947/142322) has some thoughts about accepting answers when in the position you describe.

Comment: romain-guy seems to have a different misinterpretation [here](https://www.parleys.com/play/514892280364bc17fc56c0e2/chapter10) that contradicts your opinion. - please see the last image [on my deleted question](https://web.archive.org/web/20151031182929/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28239891/whats-the-layout-logic-that-motivates-the-term-match-parent-over-fill-paren) for the quote.

Comment: @kaay I didn't go through the video but the [image](https://web.archive.org/web/20151031182929im_/https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-OHn1fLnx-FY/VNHxCFag-iI/AAAAAAAAArc/4HwNbSjwPtQ/s800/romain-guy-layout.png) you mention looks like it describes how the term is used, rather than why it was changed. Is this what you meant by "different *mis*interpretation"?

Comment: I put his words on a screencap of his presentation, and read them as "It may lead people to believe fill expands child to available space in parent. No, it means match its size". MISinterpretation, because, as I wrote, that is almost never what happens, certainly not the way he illustrated it. The video seems to be from before the name change to `match_parent` but has been quoted as relevant to it.

Comment: If you'd like me to explain or summarize something, let's try [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/39665)

Answer (score 1):

You understanding seems to be confused due to a lack of connection with the geometry involved; fill here is suggestive of colouring in, rather than filling with water. You are referring to a 2d plane, the rectangle; thus it is an area and not a volume. The padding is also a two dimensional addition to the box-plane, created by the padding rules, however they were programmed.

Filling, in this context can be rather misleading, as we will easily associate this with filling a glass, as you have done; Between the 3d realm and the 2d plane however, it is quite a different thing to fill. We fill an area, think of the paint bucket tool in many graphics programs.

Now we come to match, in this particular example, to my mind, match is referring to the actual vectors of the shape, which exist in only one dimension, length is a one dimensional object as is width also; they exist each in their own dimension perpendicular to each other. When matched they are set as equal, this it is a boolean question, the response to which is either yes or no, due tho the restriction in dimension; Match can be used also in many other situations, such as a game of tennis; We could also correctly call this a tennis match; as two competitors are matched against each other. Now returning to 'fill'; Fill does not peak of the vectors that are the parents dimensions, it is a simply order that the dumb program fill until any boundary match is made; no matter what the actual vector value is.

A child may grow to be taller than their parents; Never the less 
their genetic code will still be a match. Two lovers my make a very good match also though this is not the most romantic of descriptions.

Your two rectangles are perfectly matched in width and height; A match made in heaven perhaps? In the cloud? Or, just in a mobile phone ...

Comment: vectors, yes. I should have written "1D" rather than "2D" - each "fill" ("match") is assigned to a view's single dimension. But I feel as though I was misunderstood, twice: 1. "fill until any boundary match is made" is exactly what Google prefers to call "matching the parent". 2. Yellow and black rects are not important; the red one is supposed to `match_parent`'s height.

Comment: Remember that a mobile phone or a computer are completely and upon that totally, dumb. They look great on the outside, but their hearts are calculative and despite the great memory; they are still stupid ... You can not expect the device to interpret the semantics of correct grammatical use of the English language, it knows only that with wich it is programed, so in that light it is irrelevant which words are used.  Though this is obviously impractical for the programmer, never the less, if you are a programmer; you should be able to work this one out from the way the machine is behaving ...

Comment: ... not from semantics. What are the coordinate of the yellow rectangle, has it floated off screen? There is no apparent padding on the left of the screen, so might I assume that neither of the rectangles are fully visible? @kaay

Comment: 1. They're all fully visible. 2. I know I'm not speaking English to the computer, both `fill_parent` and `match_parent` mean `-1` to it. I'm asking why Google and others think `match` is a more fitting (pardon the pun) term for the behavior.

Comment: 3. This may be symptomatic of some other problem I have communicating in English - but, sticking to 1D/2D stuff only, I read your response as "You're mistaken. `match` is for equality only. `fill` is for using what's available". Problem is: that's exactly what I wrote that I assumed. Are you agreeing with me? If not, please point out what I've written that was misinterpreted.

Comment: You wrote of "fill" as if filling a glass of water;  This implies 3D which in this instance is wrong. "fill_parent: The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding). This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by match_parent." ~ This is very clear in my mind (I am a native English speaker); More succinct than match. Essentially the command is in binary though; It is best understand this at as low a level as you can ... @kaay

Comment: Sorry, what? I drew a parallel, the diff in the number of dimensions doesn't make it wrong. "More succinct than match" - so, are you agreeing with me that "fill" is better for this and disagreeing with Google's choice? I still can't tell. "Best at as low a level as possible" - 0101010001101111011011110010000001100110011000010111001000100001. We are talking about the chosen name for a behavior, please stay on topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39003/discussion-between-kaay-and-iain).

Answer (score 0):

I think Iain's answer is very apposite in pointing out the difference between 2D and 3D objects.

Also, having read the two articles on the Android SO that you have linked to, it seems to me that the very reason that Google are deprecating the term **fill_parent** in favour of **match_parent** is because of the very mis-understanding between the two terms that you have identified.

In other words, as I read it, Google agree with you that **fill** is often understood to to mean "taking up the *empty* internal volume"; and that if there is anything else in the container, "filling will take up the space that is left".  There they are replacing it by **match** to avoid that confusion.

Comment: Yes, it is understood to mean that... **and that's exactly what it does**, for certain kinds of parent (inside a LinearLayout with sibling views before the "filling" one; in a RelativeLayout with e.g. "toRightOf" another). As I read your answer, they've addressed the controversy by choosing a worse substitute.

Comment: @kaay  Without understanding more about what the function does in different circumstances - and I don't understand enough programming to fully understand your comments - I can't really comment further.  I agree that *match* is not ideal, but I can see why *fill* is ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry - I mean that it feels as though you *agree* with my interpretation, but misread me somewhere - which led you to write "Google know `fill_parent` better describes the behavior of using only the empty space, and THAT is why they chose `match_parent` for it"